# LibGDX: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

All of a sudden I got an error in Android Studio using LibGDX and Intel MOE for multi OS mobile development. I´ve done the sample `LibGDXMiddileCommand` multiple times before, without any problem. Now, an error comes up with this message: `"Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"`. It is pointing to this line:

```
ant.get(src: 'http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/libgdx-site/service/getVersions?release=false', dest: 'versions.json')
```

However, the given URL works fine in the browser.

In addition, something is wrong in the same gradle script. There are problems to import groovy.json.JsonSlurper.

I haven't changed anything in my machine, neither in Java nor in any other configurations. Just left my Machine like it is for about 1 month.

I am using Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.5 with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com is down. After some search online it looks like the new url is http://libgdx.com. The line above can be changed to the following.

```
ant.get(src: 'http://libgdx.com/service/versions.json', dest: 'versions.json')
```